# Better way to rewrite this .each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works fine, but I'm guessing there is a better way to rewrite this in either jQuery or vanillaJS.

**The main goal is:**

- To clone specific child elements from parent element
- Create new elements with the cloned child
  elements
- Append newly created elements to new container.

  ```
  $('.grid-block').each(function(){

      var slide = $('<div class="slide"></div>');

      $(this).find('.asset-holder img')
      .clone()
      .appendTo(slide);

      $(this).find('.asset-tools')
      .clone()
      .appendTo(slide);

      slide.appendTo('.gallery-slider');

  });`
  ```

Comment: If the code works fine, it doesn’t belong on StackOverflow, but on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: can you share html sample for grid-block

Comment: Thanks, will do. @Satpal

Comment: Whoever cast the first close vote: how did you vote to migrate to CodeReview? I don’t see that option in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you need iteration, just combine your calls to `find()`:

```
var slide = $('<div class="slide"></div>');
$('.grid-block').find('.asset-holder img, .asset-tools').clone().appendTo(slide);
slide.appendTo('.gallery-slider');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use .map()

```js
$('.grid-block').map(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    $div = $('<div class="slide"></div>');

  $this.find('.asset-holder img')
    .clone().appendTo($div);
  $this.find('.asset-tools')
    .clone().appendTo($div);

  return $div.get()
}).appendTo('.gallery-slider');
```

```css
.gallery-slider {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-block">
  <div class="asset-holder">
    <img src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=1" />
  </div>
  <div class="asset-tools">
    tools 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-block">
  <div class="asset-holder">
    <img src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=2" />
  </div>
  <div class="asset-tools">
    tools 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid-block">
  <div class="asset-holder">
    <img src="//placehold.it/64X64&text=3" />
  </div>
  <div class="asset-tools">
    tools 3
  </div>
</div>


<div class="gallery-slider"></div>
```